# Use environment variables in Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, rake-task

```
task :some_task, :environment do |t, args|
  puts Rails.env #=> development, production, etc
  puts ENV #=> {}
end
```

I set some environment variables (either via a local .env, or via Heroku Config via Herokusan), such as which AWS bucket to use, and I want to reference them in the rake task, but ENV is an empty hash. I know something related to environment gets done because of the `:environment` task dependency and that `Rails.env` has a value, but I'm not clear on the details.

So, how can I use `ENV` in a Rake task?

Comment: How are you running this task? ENV is a core Ruby thing, so it should always reflect your available environmental variables.

Comment: `$ rake some_task` in the app directory. Some of `ENV` is in `.env`, and I may need to do `$ foreman run rake task` for the Heroku stuff.

Comment: @Narfanator you should answer this as an actual answer so I can upvote you. Doing `$ foreman run rake some_task` is the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two good ways to do it:

Use Heroku's "Foreman" tool. Put all your environment variables into `.env`:

```
VAR=value
```

and run `foreman run rake some_task`.

Or (and, I'd recommend this way), using the "Figaro" gem. Put your vars into `config/application.yml`:

```
VAR: value
```

and that's it; `rake some_task`.

I'd recommend the latter, if only because `rake figaro:heroku` will push your env up as it's specified in `application.yml`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how does putting them in a .env file or application.yml keep your passwords / keys out of the codebase?  I thought that was an important reason for using ENV variables.  Isn't there some call we can make from Rake which will fetch them?

Comment: You (generally) don't check your application.yml or .env into the repo; that's what I meant by "codebase", and putting them directly into the host computer's ENV runs into its own issues. My question *is* basically asking for some call we can make from Rake, but I didn't find one.

Comment: More experienced devs at my company decided to use this pattern: `config = YAML.load("application.yml")`, but they also decided not to explain why. YMMV; I use it in some situations (ie, sinatra) and not in others (ie, rails).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the update.  Sometimes a workaround is the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody searches for another decision.
I had a trouble getting ENV variable within rake task on production server.
So I had application.yml file, but ENV['variable'] was just blank

My original command:

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm use 2.5.1 do bundle exec rake upload_source_maps_to_rollbar
```

Adding RAILS_ENV=production solved the issue:

```
RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm use 2.5.1 do bundle exec rake upload_source_maps_to_rollbar
```

Comment: Thanks - this solved it for me!
e.g. my line in Profile is now `worker: PROCESS_TYPE=WORKER RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake service:start`