# Missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've deployed a Rails 5 app to my VPS (not a Heroku instance).

Instead of the homepage, I'm getting an error message:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong
```

When I look in the production.log file, I see this error:

```
missing required :bucket option
```

I'm using Paperclip (version 5.0.0) and this is the configuration:

```
config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
s3_credentials: {
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com",
}
```

}

For my environment variables I'm using the Figaro gem.

For test purposes, I also configured to use S3 storage in development, but I'm getting the same error:

```
missing required :bucket option
```

Does anyone has experience with this error? How can I fix this?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Figaro is for local environment variables. Are those env variables on your server? You need to check. On heroku it would be `heroku config` ...you need to check the equivalent on your VPS.

Comment: I was able to fix it with this configuration settings in production.rb:   config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    bucket: Rails.application.secrets.S3_BUCKET,
    s3_region: Rails.application.secrets.S3_REGION,
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      s3_host_name: "s3-xxx-.amazonaws.com",
    }
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["missing required :bucket option" for Paperclip/S3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863938/missing-required-bucket-option-for-paperclip-s3)